# How to make document library in top level visible to subsites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'd like to ask if you came up with a solution that will allow for subsites to access a centralized document library at the parent level.  I'm still trying to no avail.  I've tried doc library templates, views, Doc Center and the best method i have OOTB is a page view web part on the subsites page display a view from the parents library.  (by the way to remove the ribbon, append ?IsDlg=1 to the url and the ribbons hidden) cool tip.  Say will you give be a Y/N on a solution that will allow one to keep a set of documents in the doc center and surface them in the sub-site.

Answer (score 2):

There are another option without such hard coding. You can open any view of your document library, as mentioned earlier AllItems.aspx for example with SharePoint Designer. Open it for editing in advanced mode (there are option when you click right mouse button on file in SP Designer). Then just point mouse cursor inside web part and chose in ribbon web parts, Add to Site gallery, see [the picture](http://gvaro.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/image5b135d308e8d8b.png). Fill in name of new web part. That is all, now you can add this web part on any page on any web site from webpart gallery through the user interface or through the SP Designer by clicking Insert, Web Part in the ribbon on any page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by editing the AllItems.aspx (or other view page) and scraping off the WebPartPages:ListViewWebPart and pasting it into a page on the subsite.

This will give you an error "List does not exits The page you selected contains a list that does not exist."

Then you need to get the WebID for the root site (where you took the ListViewWebpart from and replace the part of the webpart that looks like this:

```
<WebId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListView">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</WebId>
```

with (for example)

```
<WebId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListView">7b04dee8-b120-4dee-abea-28b77316ec7d</WebId>
```